# How to convert hashtag text into a hashtag hyperlink?

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, preg-replace, hashtag

I'm using php's `preg_replace()` to convert any words that have a hashtag symbol in front of them into hyperlinks.

So something like: `#austin` would become: `<a href="/tag/austin">#austin</a>`

Here is my regular expression.

`preg_replace('/\B#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)/', '<a href="/tag/$1">$0</a>', $text);`

My issue is: if there are any capitalized letters, the href value will retain them, but I want the href value to always be entirely lowercase.

Input: `#Austin`
Should not become: `<a href="/tag/Austin">#Austin</a>`
It should become:`<a href="/tag/austin">#Austin</a>`

How could I modify my regular expression to create these results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example using `preg_replace_callback` as suggested by @faileN:

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de5bf8fa1318b46fcc2b00e090039670eafbb678)

```
$string = '#Austin';

function hashtag_to_link($matches)
{
  return '<a href="/tag/' . strtolower($matches[1]) . '">' . $matches[0] . '</a>';
}

echo preg_replace_callback('/\B#(\w*[a-z_]+\w*)/i', 'hashtag_to_link', $string);

// output: <a href="/tag/austin">#Austin</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/\B#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)/', '<a href="/tag/$1">$0</a>', strtolower($text));
```

That will force the subject (`$text`) to be in lowercase before the regex is tested.

Comment: But the the text of the link will also be lowercase.

Comment: That appears to be what OP wants.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, I want the actually words casing to remain the same.. so #Austin would be `<a href="/tag/austin">#Autsin</a>`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with `preg_replace_callback`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can use `e` modifier which lets you use PHP functions in the replacement string:

```
preg_replace('/\B#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)/e', "'<a href=\"/tag/'.strtolower('$1').'\">$0</a>'", $text);
```

Comment: This method was [deprecated from PHP5.5 and removed from PHP7](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (but the logic is good)